# Fade in & Fade out at the same time

Tags: java, android, android-animation

I am using this part of code to create the animation:

```
private void animate(final ImageView imageView, final Drawable[] images, final int imageIndex,
                         final boolean forever) {

        //imageView <-- The View which displays the images
        //images[] <-- Holds R references to the images to display
        //imageIndex <-- index of the first image to show in images[]
        //forever <-- If equals true then after the last image it starts all over again with the
        // first image resulting in an infinite loop. You have been warned.

        int fadeInDuration = 1000; // Configure time values here
        int timeBetween = 300;
        int fadeOutDuration = 1000;

        imageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);    //Visible or invisible by default -
        // this will apply when the animation ends
        imageView.setImageDrawable(images[imageIndex]);

        Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
        fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); // add this
        fadeIn.setDuration(fadeInDuration);

        Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
        fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); // and this
        fadeOut.setStartOffset(fadeInDuration + timeBetween);
        fadeOut.setDuration(fadeOutDuration);

        AnimationSet animation = new AnimationSet(false); // change to false
        animation.addAnimation(fadeIn);
        animation.addAnimation(fadeOut);
        animation.setRepeatCount(1);
        imageView.setAnimation(animation);

        animation.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener() {
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
                if (images.length - 1 > imageIndex) {
                    animate(imageView, images, imageIndex + 1, forever); //Calls itself until it gets to the end of the array
                } else {
                    if (forever) {
                        animate(imageView, images, 0, forever);  //Calls itself to start the animation all
                        // over again in a loop if forever = true
                    }
                }
            }

            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }

            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            }
        });
    }
```

That piece of code works, the problem is that there's nothing between the fade in and fade out which makes you see whats under those picture (white screen).
I want the fade in to start **while** the fade out is running so you won't see the white background but always the pictures.
I've tried changing the **timeBetween** value to be zero (and even negative) which should change the offset of the second animation which will lead to the animations starting at the same time but without success - It only makes the image disappear faster and still doesn't make the requested effect (Fade in and Fade out together)

Could anyone explain how is it possible to make fade in and fade out activate simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to do this is to have *two* `ImageView`s, both inside the same `FrameLayout` so that they overlap (which can also be done with `RelativeLayout`).

Top `ImageView` gets image 1.

Bottom `ImageView` gets image 2.

Animate top `ImageView` alpha from 1 to 0.

As top `ImageView` fades out, bottom `ImageView` becomes visible.

After animation ends, switch bottom image to top and set alpha back to 1.

Load new image in bottom

Repeat animation

Comment: What if I have more than 2 ImageViews, let's say 10?

Answer (score 0):

Hi I was looking for a solution and found this Question.

I used Bitmaps for my solutions but I'm sure you can change it back.

Same is true for using the 2 imageviews (not passed with function)

This is my solution:

```
    private void animate(final Bitmap[] images, final int imageIndex, final boolean forever) {

    final ImageView imageView0 = mImageSlideShow0;
    final ImageView imageView1 = mImageSlideShow1;

    imageView0.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    imageView1.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);


    AnimationSet animationIn = null;
    AnimationSet animationOut = null;

    //images[] <-- Holds R references to the images to display
    //imageIndex <-- index of the first image to show in images[]
    //forever <-- If equals true then after the last image it starts all over again with the first image resulting in an infinite loop. You have been warned.

    int fadeDuration = 1000; // Configure time values here

    Animation fadeIn = new AlphaAnimation(0, 1);
    fadeIn.setInterpolator(new DecelerateInterpolator()); // add this
    fadeIn.setDuration(fadeDuration);


    Animation fadeOut = new AlphaAnimation(1, 0);
    fadeOut.setInterpolator(new AccelerateInterpolator()); // and this
    fadeOut.setStartOffset( 2 * fadeDuration);  //time that image is visible without any animations
    fadeOut.setDuration(fadeDuration);

    animationIn = new AnimationSet(false); // change to false
    animationIn.addAnimation(fadeIn);
    animationIn.setRepeatCount(1);

    animationOut = new AnimationSet(false); // change to false
    animationOut.addAnimation(fadeOut);
    animationOut.setRepeatCount(1);

    int animationInIndex = imageIndex;
    int animationOutIndex = 0;

    //if first image take last one in array
    if(imageIndex != 0)
    {
        animationOutIndex = animationInIndex - 1;
    }
    else
    {
        animationOutIndex = images.length - 1;
    }

    //select the correct fade in / fade out view
    if(mCurrentImageViewActive == 0)
    {
        //set correct image image view
        imageView0.setImageBitmap(images[animationInIndex]);
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(images[animationOutIndex]);

        //set correct animation image view
        imageView0.setAnimation(animationIn);
        imageView1.setAnimation(animationOut);

        //set next fade in view
        mCurrentImageViewActive = 1;
    }
    else
    {
        imageView1.setImageBitmap(images[animationInIndex]);
        imageView0.setImageBitmap(images[animationOutIndex]);

        imageView1.setAnimation(animationIn);
        imageView0.setAnimation(animationOut);

        //set next fade in view
        mCurrentImageViewActive = 0;
    }

    //if fade out is done call next action
    animationOut.setAnimationListener(new Animation.AnimationListener()
    {
        public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation)
        {
            if (images.length - 1 > imageIndex)
            {
                animate(images, imageIndex + 1,forever); //Calls itself until it gets to the end of the array
            }
            else
            {
                if (forever)
                {
                    animate( images, 0,forever);  //Calls itself to start the animation all over again in a loop if forever = true
                }
            }
        }
        public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
        public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        }
    });
}
```